# Upgrading from Python 3.5.1 to 3.6: SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am on Windows 8.1 and wanted to upgrade from Python 3.5.1 to Python 3.6. I currently use Anaconda3 and have virtual environments for python 2.7 and python 3.5.

I used the following way of upgrading:
 Before upgradation-

```
C:\Users\thisuser>python --version 
Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
```

Upgradation done using:

```
C:\Users\thisuser>conda install python=3.6
```

The above ran successfully and the progress was complete.

But after this point, I am unable to run any python code because of the following issue:

```
C:\Users\thisuser>python
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thisuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 73, in <module
>
    import os
  File "C:\Users\thisuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 652, in <module>

    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "C:\Users\thisuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\_collections_abc.py", line 64

    async def _ag(): yield
                    ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function
```

No matter what I do, whether trying to run an existing python code or activate python2 environment or pre-existing python3 enviroment, I get the exact same error as above. Checking the python version gives the same as before i.e.,

```
C:\Users\thisuser>python --version 
Python 3.5.1 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

**Edit1:**
Found this bug report: https://bugs.python.org/review/28003/diff/18396/Lib/types.py?context=50&column_width=80

Can't understand how to make use of this to fix the issue. Have tried commenting out the relevant portion of the code in _collections_abc.py but this leads to other strange errors.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with conda, it has to do with python 3.5/3.6

Comment: That bugs.python.org link isn't a bug report; it's a glimpse of a code change to the Python standard library, and only happens to be available on bugs.python.org for code review purposes.

Comment: per jwodders comment on my deleted answer, it looks like its still running 3.5.  Can you print out `python --version`?

Comment: As mentioned in the question description, the version remains the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `python` executable you are using is old, even though the library paths point to `python3.6`.

Add `C:\Users\thisuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\bin` to the beginning of your `PATH` variable. Or alternatively, run python from `C:\Users\thisuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\bin\python`.

Answer (score 0):

(Windows 10)
I had same issue but realized that the "Project Interpreter" on my Pycharm was still set to 3.5 while PYTHONPATH was set to 3.6 executable.  Changed "Project Interpreter" to 3.6 and issue solved