# Anaconda new environment gives me python SyntaxError 'yield' inside async function

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, environment-variables, anaconda

Ok, I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I did found some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397926/upgrading-from-python-3-5-1-to-3-6-syntaxerror-yield-inside-async-function) but I'm still stuck.

I have Anaconda 3 (python 3.6) on Windows.
Created a new environment using

> conda create --tf python=3.5

That works just fine and in cmd I can activate it. But I get this nice error when running python.

[image]

I kind of get the idea my issue is my win environment variables.
But I have tried to added my Anaconda path to the beginning of my path variable and my new tf environment path to the beginning. But no luck. Is this some sort of conflict between python 3.6 and 3.5.

Thanks

Comment: Somehow or other you're trying to import from your root install even within your activated env.  When using Anaconda, you shouldn't have PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME set-- could you see if they are?

Comment: Well done!!! It works 100%. I can't thank you enough seriously I have been struggling for so long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Moved from comments]

Somehow or other you're trying to import from your root install even within your activated env, and that root install (being Python 3.6) uses async + yield in its stdlib, which isn't supported in the 3.5 you want to use.

When using Anaconda, you shouldn't have either PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME set (and if there are other PYTHON* environment variables set, might as well clear them too!)

These cause problems because these variables are very powerful and the interpreter winds up obeying them.  In the case of multiple environments and/or multiple Python distributions on the same system, it's best to leave them alone.